# Second DocumentRoot for certain URLS

Tags: linux, apache-2.2

I have the following setup in my apache-config:

> ```
>  <VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:80>
>
>     ServerName   example.com:80
>     ServerAlias  www.example.com
>
>     DocumentRoot /var/www/page
>
>     <Location "/blog">
>
>       DocumentRoot /var/www/blog
>
>     </Location>
>
>     RailsBaseURI /
>     RailsEnv development
>
>  </VirtualHost>
> ```

However,

Apache tells me, I am not allowed to have a second `DocumentRoot`.
How can I make "www.example.com/blog" point to "/var/www/blog"?

I'm sure this is basic, but I just can't find the proper documentation online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
Alias /blog /var/www/blog
```

instead of the whole `<Location>` directive.

Comment: Hm yeah that seems to be the right approach. I also added a <Directory> section for that directory, however, the /blog request is still passed on to DocumentRoot directory. Am I missing something?

Comment: Ah got it. Since the other URL was running Passenger I needed to add a "PassengerEnabled off" and "AllowOverride All" to the <Directory> referenced by Alias. Now it works. 

Thanks hop!